# Unable to get data from my form into datatables request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables-1.10

In my code, I'm attempting to get data from 3 inputs in a form control.
However, when I click Submit, no data is captured and the page reloads.
The submit is triggering table.draw(), as expected, but none of the values in the input is being captured and added to the Request.
I have attempted to pull the value directly, within the ajax block, and into separate vars in a submit function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
# $Id$
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head     content must come *after* these tags -->
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/apirpt.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Status</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top:20px">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Status Report</h1>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="reqid">ReqID:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     name="reqID" placeholder="Enter Req ID here" id="reqID">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="start">Start Date:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"     name="dtStart" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="dtStart">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="end">End Date:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dtEnd" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="dtEnd">
                        </div>
                        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                        <table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-    bordered display compact" width="100%" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                   <th>Code</th>
                                   <th>From</th>
                                   <th>To</th>
                                   <th>Req ID</th>
                                   <th>Transaction Date</th>
                                   <th>Old Code Status</th>
                                   <th>New Code Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                   <th>Code</th>
                                   <th>From</th>
                                   <th>To</th>
                                   <th>Req ID</th>
                                   <th>Transaction Date</th>
                                   <th>Old Code Status</th>
                                   <th>New Code Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#grid tfoot th').each(function() {
               var title = $('#grid thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
               $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' +     title + '"/>');
           });
           var vReqID;
           var table = $('#grid').DataTable({
                "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                "ajax": {
                        "url" : "data/get_status.php",
                        data: function(data) {
                             //$('form').serialize();
                             data.dtStart = $("#dtStart").val();
                             data.dtEnd = $("#dtEnd").val();
                             data.reqID = vReqID; //$("#reqID").val();
                          }
                        },
                "processing" : false,
                "serverSide" : true,
                "fixedHeader" : true,
                "lengthMenu" : [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200],[10,25,50,100,200]],
                "pageLength" : 25,
                "sScrollX" : "110%",
                "sScrollY" : "600px",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "type": "signed-num", "targets": 3}
                ]
            });
            table.columns().every(function () {
               var datatableColumn = this;
               $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function()     {
                   datatableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
               });
           });
           $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(event){
               vReqID = $("#reqID").val();
               //vStart = $("#dtStart").val();
               //vEnd = $("#dtEnd").val();
               //alert(vReqID);
               table.draw();
           });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Within the data element of the ajax call, it appears to only work with static data. I need to be able to send parameters to my url, dynamically.

```
data: function(data) { 
    return $.extend( {}, data, { 
      "dtStart" : "2/1/2017", //$('#dtStart').val(), 
      "dtEnd" : "2/28/2017",  //$('#dtEnd').val(), 
      "reqID" : "451"         //$('#reqID').val()
    });
```

This is the request, notice the last 3 variables are empty.  Those should contain my values.

```
GET /data/get_status.php?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=6&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&search%5Bregex%5D=false&dtStart=&dtEnd=&reqID=&_=1489602817698 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8088
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8088/report_status.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Comment: Where is the PHP?

Comment: Your form elements need names.

Comment: Where is the name attribute for the input tags?

Comment: please mention the ajax form post code.

Comment: name got cut when I copy/pasted.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Examples), have you tried

```
"ajax": {
    url: "data/get_status.php",
    data: function (d) {
        // merge object d with new object
        return $.extend({}, d, {
            dtStart: $("#dtStart").val(),
            dtEnd: $("#dtEnd").val(),
            reqID: $("#reqID").val()
        });
    }
}
```

[These answers](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21940/how-to-pass-new-post-parameters-on-ajax-reload) use similar approach.

By default, when you click on a `type="submit"` button, it will send the form-data somewhere (usually to the address specified in the form's `action` attribute). One way to disable this from happening, is to simply change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. This will stop your form from submitting upon clicking on the button as you will handling it with the `table.draw()` that should trigger the AJAX.

Comment: Changing to the button type fixed my code.  Thank you